# How to use php pattern Regex in Delphi

Tags: php, regex, delphi

Most of the time, when I look for a Regex pattern I get it from some php code, and then I need to "traslate" to Delphi. The big problem in Delphi is that php escapes doesn't Works in Delphi, but if you ignore them most of the time everything is ok. But not in the next example, where if you remove /x from the pattern, the function preg_match_all doesn't output any value.

This is the code in php:

```
 $pattern = "/\n".
     "\s(counters?\\([^)]*\\))|\n".
     "\A(counters?\\([^)]*\\))|\n".
     "\s([\"']) ( (?:[^\"']|\\\\[\"'])+ )(?<!\\\\)\\3|\n".
     "\A([\"']) ( (?:[^\"']|\\\\[\"'])+ )(?<!\\\\)\\5|\n" .
     "\s([^\s\"']+)|\n" .
     "\A([^\s\"']+)\n".
     "/xi";

    preg_match_all($pattern, '"File " counter(File)', $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

This is the output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '"File "' (length=7)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string '"' (length=1)
      6 => string 'File ' (length=5)
 1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string ' counter(File)' (length=14)
```

This is what I've done in Delphi:

```
 type
 TMatches = Array of Array of String;
 var
   matches: TMatches;
 pattern :=  '/\n'+
   '\s(counters?\\([^)]*\\))|\n'+
   '\A(counters?\\([^)]*\\))|\n'+
   '\s([\"'']) ( (?:[^\"'']|\\\\[\"''])+ )(?<!\\\\)\\3|\n'+
   '\A([\"'']) ( (?:[^\"'']|\\\\[\"''])+ )(?<!\\\\)\\5|\n'+
   '\s([^\s\"'']+)|\n'+
   '\A([^\s\"'']+)\n'+
   '/xi';

   RegExMatchAll(pattern,'"Page " counter(page)',matches);
```

The function RegExMatchAll I get it from here and Works in most of the case:

```
    procedure RegExMatchAll(Pattern: String; Subject: String; out Matches: TMatches);
    var D, sD: integer; RegEx: TRegEx; RegGroupColl: TGroupCollection; RegColl: TMatchCollection;
    begin
      RegEx := TRegEx.Create(Pattern);
      RegColl := RegEx.Matches(Subject);
      SetLength(Matches, RegColl.Count); // Numero de coincidencias [array [X]]
      for D := 0 to RegColl.Count - 1 do
      begin
         RegGroupColl := RegColl.Item[D].Groups;
         SetLength(Matches[D], RegGroupColl.Count); // Numero de grupos [array [D][sD]]
         for sD := 0 to RegGroupColl.Count - 1 do Matches[D][sD] := RegGroupColl.Item[sD].Value;
      end;
    end;
```

Also I change \n to #13#10, and doesn't really matter, matches array is empty.I know if a difficult pattern regex, but if at last we can resolve this issue, it would be wonderful, there is a lot of php regex code and if we can know how to use it in Delphi it is going to be great for Delphi developers.

Comment: Which regex flavour are you using? Delphi has built in regex support since XE using PCRE. The various regex flavours have documentation so there's no need for you to be stuck. You can read the documentation. That would be a lot easier than cut and paste regexes that you don't understand and then using trial and error.

Comment: As much as I don't like RTFMish answers I'm gonna have to agree with David here. A good starter would be [regular-expressions.info's Delphi page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html) which speaks about getting the matches with `.Item[]` etc. I'm unfamiliar with Delphi but this should help you get on the right track. Both PHP as well as Delphi use the same PCRE regex-flavor so the syntax of the regex itself should not be very different.

Comment: There appear to be far too many backslashes in the Delphi code. Remember that roughly half of them are there to escape the PHP string, but that's not necessary in Delphi strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, PHP's regex support is built on PCRE. As is Delphi's which is what you appear to be using. Although I'm guessing there because nowhere do you state this. However, I think it's a reasonably safe assumption.

The `x` modifier in PHP corresponds to the `PCRE_EXTENDED` flag. In Delphi the corresponding setting is the [`roIgnorePatternSpace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegExOption) option. Pass that option when you call `Matches`.

One aside. Please don't post important code using off-site links. We should not have to leave the question to learn what your code is. A reader should be able to get all the information direct from the question. As it is, a reader would wonder how this answer discerns which Delphi regex library you use, and that you are calling `Matches`.

Comment: Yes, the problem was to add the roIgnorePatternSpace option. With that, Works perfectly.